# Trying to block the name Pat with a regular expression

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-3

For a ruby on rails assignment I am supposed to block anyone with the name Pat. I do not want to black names such as Patrick though.
Right now I have

```
validates :author, :format => {:without => /pat/i}
```

The above validations will of course also block names such as Patrick
I have tried the regular expression below and it didn't catch Pat unless there was a space or something else that is not a character.

```
/pat\W/i
```

I am unsure how to make it so it only catches a name that contains Pat but not a name with a Pat in it such as Patrick. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

/\bpat\b/i

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ^ and $ operators.

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is a handy tool to test these out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(\s+|^)pat(\s+|$)/i
```

It matches a string with `pat` followed by any number of whitespace characters **or** a string that ends with `pat`.